# Pass an array into jquery attr(), for one property

Tags: jquery

Can I Pass an array into jquery attr  for one property, such as follow

```
$("th[id={x,y}]")
```

it look like "where in" condination at SQL. My wants such as it, $("th[id={x,y}]") is th's id equal one of these? I want to ask it! Do you use any where-in condition in sql.. My wants like it.

Comment: What do you want to do? The `alt` only takes in a string.

Comment: why would u want to pass an array ? it would just print out `object object` as it expects plain text

Comment: on a side note, {} is an object, not an array.

Comment: My wants such as it, $("th[id={x,y}]")  is th's id equal one of these? I want to ask it! Do you use any where-in condition in sql.. My wants like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]
*the question has been modified to clarify what he wants, so I've removed the inapplicable parts of my answer...*

JQuery (and CSS) allows you to use multiple selectors together:

For example:

```
$('[id=x], [id=y], [id=z]')
```

...will select all elements in your page with either of your possible `id` values.

Alternatively, if you only want to find them within `$(this)`, you would use the `find()` method:

```
$(this).find('[id=x], [id=y], [id=z]')
```

Hope that answers you're question.

Depending on the values you're searching for, you may also be interested in [more advanced attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). For example, if your `x`, `y` and `z` options all begin with the same string, you could use the attribute prefix selector:

```
$('[id|=prefix]')
```

or if they all contain a particular word:

```
$('[id~=word]')
```

there are a number of possible options; that should give you a start, but see the JQuery manual for more information: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 5):

***EDIT: you asked:***

> My wants such as it, $("th[id={x,y}]")
>   is th's id equal one of these? I want
>   to ask it! Do you use any where-in
>   condition in sql.. My wants like it

I assume you are looking for a way to select multiple `<th>` elements based on one or more ids. You can simply **chain selectors** like this:

```
$('th#x, th#y, th#z'); // will return 3 elements, if they exist
```

***Original answer:***

**No.**

[`jQuery.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is used to set valid properties on HTML objects.

**If you want to store arbitrary data linked to a HTML object, use [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).**

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for your needs - replace ***{*** with ***"***?

```
$(this).attr("alt","1,2,3")
```

Comment: My wants such as it, $("th[id={x,y}]") is th's id equal one of these? I want to ask it! Do you use any where-in condition in sql.. My wants like it